# why dont starfleet ships use abandoned ship's warp cores as weapons? (using galaxy class cores)

Tags: star-trek

wouldn't it make some sort of sense to use an abandoned ship's warp core as a weapon, say against a Borg cube? like let's say a ship has been long abandoned, cant you give the order to fling it into a said cube, and detonate it? please do bring up the generations explosion, I'm not sure of the range of a warp core breach, but for this let's use a galaxy class.
Edit: I mean in-universe why, and the abandoned ships would be adrift, like wolf 359. the ships don't seem to have suffered a warp core breach, as many seem to be intact mostly. unless I'm wrong. I have gotten banned twice because I ask stupid questions

Comment: Are you looking for in-universe explanations of the tactic?

Comment: Where do you propose to get "abandoned" ships from in the first place?

Comment: “give the order to fling it into a said cube, and detonate it?” — how? Starfleet ships appear to need several crew members to make them move even when they’re in perfect working order. I don’t think we see any indication that you can remotely autopilot them towards an enemy target in the middle of a battle.

Comment: Note that a good weapon doesn't simply comprise a big boom; a good weapon involves a way to _deliver_ a big boom to a target accurately and before it can move, intercept, or destroy it.

Comment: Because it's not Star Wars?    When there's forty years of established canon that suggests it can't be done (even if we the audience don't know what that reason it), they don't arbitrarily just undo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a TOS episode called "The Doomsday Machine" where that comprises the plot of the episode.  I think the reason it's not more common is that there's not always an abandoned ship available.  It also might be impractical to transport additional powered warp cores.  It seems like if you had the room, you'd just make your own engines larger - and there's no reason to think that an unpowered warp core would breach as spectacularly.  The amount of power needed to maximize the effects of a warp breach is probably about the same as that needed to power the ship.